# How do I find the temperature of an object being heated on one side and cooled on the other

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Ok so i'm trying to figure out what temperature a beam would be when one end is put into the ground and the other side is in the open air above. Assuming the beam is perfectly insulated besides the part underground being cooled by the earth (50 f, 10 C) and the part above ground being heated by the ambient air temperature (80 f, 30 C). I want to know how I can find the temperature of the part of beam above ground or even just what the average temperature of the beam would be. Ant ideas on how to calculate this?

Comment: It isn't clear what part of the beam is insulated.  Are you saying that, above ground,  only the very top surface of the beam is in contact with the air?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with electric circuits this method is useful:

1. The temperature difference between 2 parts of a conducting body acts the same way as when you have a potential difference between 2 parts of a conducting wire.
2. The heat conductivity is equivalent to the electric conductivity of the wire which is inverse of its resistance.
3. And the last thing is rate of heat conducted through the beam(heat current) which is equivalent to rate of charge conducted through the wire (electric current).

You also need to know the conductivity of heat of the beam if you want to know the time when the temperatures become stable.

Now just go on doing it the way you do in electric circuits. This method helps the most while problem solving as that is what is required in your question. Also,  i would advice you to know the fundamentals of heat conductivity before doing by this method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you really need the conductivity to answer this question (assuming the conductivity is uniform throughout)?

Comment: @garyp i realized its not essential.  It would have been if the time was also asked.  Thanks

Comment: Ok.  I would suggest that you edit your post.  (See the "edit" link?)

Comment: @garyp Did it while you were commenting :)